# Activating the Spartan Refactoring plugin on a Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I just downloaded the Spartan Refactoring Eclipse plug-in (from https://www.spartan.org.il/). I'm trying to run it on a Java project in Eclipse, however it doesn't display any code improvement suggestions.

How do I tell the plug-in to analyze my current project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on your project in Eclipse, then tick the `Spartanization -> Enable Spartanization Suggestions` option. If it's the first time you're doing it for your project, and the option is already ticked, try unticking it and ticking it again.

[image: Enable Spartanization Suggestions]